# libfreenect - depth registration theory

Tags: computer-vision, openframeworks, camera-calibration

I've been hacking around with the Kinect for a while now using ofxKinect with openFrameworks. I've been using the built in depth registration by doing:

```
kinect.setRegistration(true);
```

Which I think invokes a registration function provided by the underlying libfreenect library. I tried having a look at the source code for libfreenect to figure out the theory behind what it's doing to register the depth map to the RGB image, but I'm really quite confused by it all.

The code is here: https://github.com/ofTheo/ofxKinect/blob/master/libs/libfreenect/registration.c

Does anyone have any idea what the theory is behind the technique being implemented by this code? Even if you could just point me to a paper that employs a similar technique, that would be pretty helpful.

Comment: I managed to find a related paper if anyone else is interested. http://www.ee.oulu.fi/~dherrera/kinect/2011-depth_calibration.pdf